# What medical condition was this "epilepsy that causes mental instability at all times"?

Tags: history, medicine, edim-witnesses

Rambam's [Laws of Testimony 9:8](http://mechon-mamre.org/i/e209.htm) (written about 800 years ago) describe disqualification for testimony (*eidut*) due to mental instability. He writes:

> The epileptic is disqualified when having a seizure, but valid when not having a seizure; this assumes that when he is not having a seizure, he is completely mentally competent; as some epileptics have mixed-up minds all the time ...

Any guess what modern medical condition the latter would be? (My understanding is that there are many different types of epilepsy out there.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this?

From a [Danish professor's page on epilepsy](http://www.epilepsy.dk/Handbook/Mental-complications-uk.asp#NOTCONNECTED):

> Hallucinations
>
> People with temporal lobe epilepsy, more often than others, may develop a mental condition which resembles schizophrenia. This manifests itself most often when the person has had complex partial seizures with convulsions for about 15 years. The person gets the feeling that they are being persecuted and develops hallucinations.

Comment: Right! Additionally there are numerous psychiatric symptoms that may be. linked to epilepsy. There are also illnesses in which seizures are one of the symptoms. There are ictal states called partial, without nefila, which occurs between nefolot, with distorsions in remembering